# Exjts4 grid remote summary (no grouping)

Tags: grid, extjs4, server-side, summary

I've created Ext.grid.Panel and now I need to make a summary with data calculated on server. And I have no grouping in that grid.

In feature `ftype: 'summary'` there is no such property like 'remoteRoot'.
Is there any opportunity to create this summary withou grouping?

Comment: Does it allow to get data from AJAX-request? I didn't find such example..

Comment: anyway I need one summary row, and not expandable extra-rows

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend / override class. This is an example based on AbstractSummary.js and should be optimised.

```js
// usage in grid:
{
  ftype : 'summary',
  remoteRoot : 'summary'
}

//response from server
{
   data : [] // our standard data
   summary : {
      summaryField : 123123
   }
}

// our class
Ext.define('w3desApp.grid.feature.Summary', {
 override : 'Ext.grid.feature.Summary',
 getSummary: function(store, type, field, group) {
    var reader = store.proxy.reader;
    if (this.remoteRoot && reader.rawData) {
        // reset reader root and rebuild extractors to extract summaries data
        root = reader.root;
        reader.root = this.remoteRoot;
        reader.buildExtractors(true);
        summaryRow = reader.getRoot(reader.rawData);
        // restore initial reader configuration
        reader.root = root;
        reader.buildExtractors(true);
        if (typeof summaryRow[field] != 'undefined') {
            return summaryRow[field];
        }

        return '';
    }

    return this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```